# gridPanel height 0 in IE11 using ExtJS-3.2

Tags: jsp, internet-explorer, extjs, struts, internet-explorer-11

I'm updating to IE11 a webapp that uses ExtJS-3.2.

My problem is a series of 4 gridPanels that IE11 interpretates ok the first gridPanel, but the other 3 interpretes with `height:0` when in code specifies `height:282`.

The first gridPanel that's OK:

```
        //Here is the "query"
        var datosProductos = [
            <logic:iterate name="consultaMultipleForm" property="listaActivos1" id="productos" indexId="index">
                <c:if test="${index != 0}"> , </c:if>
                [
                    '<bean:write name="productos" property="idTipo" />',
                    '<bean:write name="productos" property="descripcionTipo" />'
                ]
            </logic:iterate>
        ];
        storeProductos = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
            proxy: dameProxy( 'GIConsultaMultiple.do' ),
            autoLoad: false,
            fields: [
               {name: 'ID'},
               {name: 'nombre'}
            ],
               data: datosProductos
        });
        // I think here is the important part
        gridProductos = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
            columnWidth:.14,
            store: storeProductos,
            id: 'productosGrid',
            bodyStyle: 'border:1px solid #99BBE8',
            autoScroll : true,
            height: 282,                
            frame: true,
            columns: [
                {id: 'nombreProductoID', header: '<span style="font-size:10px; font-weight:bold"><bean:message key="gestionInventarios.consultaMultiple.resultado.tabla1.cabecera" /></span>',
                    renderer: pintaFilaProducto, width: 20, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'nombre'}
            ],
            stripeRows: true,
            minColumnWidth: 10,
            sm: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({
                singleSelect:true
            }),             
            plain:true,
            border: true,
            loadMask: new Ext.LoadMask( Ext.getBody(), {
                msg:'<bean:message key="generic.label.cargando"/>'
            }),
            style: 'text-align: left;',             
            autoExpandColumn: 'nombreProductoID'
        });
        gridProductos.on('rowdblclick', function(gridProductos, rowIndex, e) {
            consulta_multiple(storeProductos.getAt(rowIndex).data, "0");
        });
        gridProductos.on('rowclick', function(gridProductos, rowIndex, e) {
            ver_detalle(storeProductos.getAt(rowIndex).data.ID, "0");
        });
```

And here is the second gridPanel (the others are the same but with other IDs and datas.

```
            var datosProcesos = [
            <logic:iterate name="consultaMultipleForm" property="listaActivos2" id="procesos" indexId="index">
                <c:if test="${index != 0}"> , </c:if>
                [
                    '<bean:write name="procesos" property="idTipo" />',
                    '<bean:write name="procesos" property="descripcionTipo" />'
                ]
            </logic:iterate>
        ];
        storeProcesos = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
            proxy: dameProxy( 'GIConsultaMultiple.do' ),
            autoLoad: false,
            fields: [
               {name: 'ID'},
               {name: 'nombre'}
            ],
               data: datosProcesos
        });
        gridProcesos = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
            columnWidth:.14,
            store: storeProcesos,
            id: 'procesosGrid',
            bodyStyle: 'border:1px solid #99BBE8',
            autoScroll : true,
            height: 282,
            frame: true,
            columns: [
                {id: 'nombreProcesoID', header: '<span style="font-size:10px; font-weight:bold"><bean:message key="gestionInventarios.consultaMultiple.resultado.tabla2.cabecera" /></span>',
                    renderer: pintaFilaProducto, width: 20, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'nombre'}
            ],
            stripeRows: true,
            minColumnWidth: 50,
            sm: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({
                singleSelect:true
            }),
            plain:true,
            border: true,
            loadMask: new Ext.LoadMask( Ext.getBody(), {
                msg:'<bean:message key="generic.label.cargando"/>'
            }),
            style: 'text-align: left;',
            autoExpandColumn: 'nombreProcesoID'
        });
        gridProcesos.on('rowdblclick', function(gridProcesos, rowIndex, e) {
            consulta_multiple(storeProcesos.getAt(rowIndex).data, "1");
        });
        gridProcesos.on('rowclick', function(gridProcesos, rowIndex, e) {
            ver_detalle(storeProcesos.getAt(rowIndex).data.ID, "1");
        });
```

and now a screens with the differences.

Here is how IE11 shows the web (bad): http://i62.tinypic.com/w02amg.png
Here is how Chrome shows the web (good): http://i59.tinypic.com/w2czfr.png

At this point I have tried many things (height: 100% isolate regions ... but nothing has helped me and I'm pretty lost).

If anyone could lend a hand would be eternally grateful (apart from better understand ext-JS)

---

### **Solved!**

I explain the slight modification in case anyone has the same error

Only i removed the line

```
 height: 282,
```

and added the new height in Bodystyle line

```
bodyStyle: 'border:1px solid #99BBE8; height: 276px',
```

The complete code is:

```
 gridProcesos = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
            columnWidth:.14,
            store: storeProcesos,
            id: 'procesosGrid',
            bodyStyle: 'border:1px solid #99BBE8; height: 276px;',
            autoScroll : true,
            frame: true,
            columns: [
                {id: 'nombreProcesoID', header: '<span style="font-size:10px; font-weight:bold"><bean:message key="gestionInventarios.consultaMultiple.resultado.tabla2.cabecera" /></span>',
                    renderer: pintaFilaProducto, width: 20, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'nombre'}
            ],
            stripeRows: true,
            minColumnWidth: 50,
            sm: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({
                singleSelect:true
            }),
            plain:true,
            border: true,
            loadMask: new Ext.LoadMask( Ext.getBody(), {
                msg:'<bean:message key="generic.label.cargando"/>'
            }),
            style: 'text-align: left;',
            autoExpandColumn: 'nombreProcesoID'
        });
```

Now it works perfectly.

Comment: If you found solution for the problem post it as an answer.

Comment: I tried but I cant post as an answer until 8 hours later.